# What's the difference between scipy.misc.imresize and skimage.transform.resize?

Tags: python, resize, scikit-image

I am trying to replace some code which uses `scipy.misc.imresize` with `skimage.transform.resize`. However, I am struggling to understand some code which performs some math on the results:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage.transform import resize as imresize

# load the image
filename = os.path.join('silhouettes', 'cat.jpg')
image = Image.open(filename)

data = np.asarray(image)
width, height, _ = data.shape
mask = imresize(data, (width, height), order=3).astype('float32')
print(type(mask))

# Perform binarization of mask
mask[mask <= 127] = 0
mask[mask > 128] = 255

# numpy.amax
# Return the maximum of an array or maximum along an axis.
max = np.amax(mask)
print(max)

# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
# Attempt to divide an numpy.ndarray by 0
mask /= max
```

The comments document the error I'm getting: The `max` value is `0`, and I wind up trying to divide by `0`. For reference, the original function was:

```py
def load_mask_sil(invert_sil, shape):
    width, height, _ = shape
    mask = imresize(invert_sil, (width, height), interp='bicubic').astype('float32')

    # Perform binarization of mask
    mask[mask <= 127] = 0
    mask[mask > 128] = 255

    max = np.amax(mask)
    mask /= max

    return mask
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation on [`skimage.transform.resize`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.18.x/api/skimage.transform.html#resize), the values in the output are scaled to the interval `[0.0 ... 1.0]`, whereas I assume, that `scipy.misc.imresize` didn't change the data type or values at all (I don't have such an old version of `scipy` at hand to verify that).

So, in the original version, you most likely had values in the range `[0.0 ... 255.0]`, and some values above `128`, so that the maximum was `255`. In the new version, you only have values in the range `[0.0 ... 1.0]`, thus all pixels will be set to `0`, since they're all below `127`. (On a side note: Why `<= 127` and `> 128`? What about `128` itself?)

You can circumvent that issue by enabling the `preserve_range` flag in your `skimage.transform.resize` call:

```py
mask = imresize(data, (width, height), order=3, preserve_range=True).astype('float32')
```

So, you again get values in the range `[0.0 ... 255.0]`, which should resemble the original behaviour.